# Function in R to check the type of an element

Tags: r

My task is to create a function which checks if the element of a vector either a number or a character. But the problem is that i have a vector with different types of data. Why does not my code work?

```
vector <- c(10L, 3.8, FALSE, "HELLO")

#enter code here

data_types <- function(x = vector){
   for(i in 1:length(x)){
     if(is.character(as.character(x[i]))){
        print('it is a character')}
   else if(is.numeric(as.numeric(x[i]))){
        print('it is a number')}
   else {
        print('neither number nor a character')}
  }
}
data_types()
```

Comment: In R, in a vector, if one element is `character` than *all* elements are `character`, there can be no mixing of classes within a vector. FYI, `function(x = vector)` ... this is not declaring that `x` should be a vector, this is saying that the first argument is `x`, and if not provided by the user, then `x` will be the literal value of `vector`, which means `x` will be a *function*, and your `data_types` will fail.

Comment: Another fyi, `is.character(as.character(x[i]))` will either (a) be true, because if something can be coerced to `character`, it will, and then pass the `is.*` test; or (b) fail, because some things cannot be coerced to `character` (such as `base::vector`, a function, the default value of `x` if the user does not provide one).

Comment: Yet another fyi: I now re-see the question and see that you have defined a `vector` outside of the code block, my bad. This doesn't make `x=vector` a good default value, though: it relies on the presence of an object defined in the calling environment which, if not defined, will result in the *function* `vector` being used, which will produce errors.

Comment: Last one: `c(10L, 3.8, FALSE, "HELLO")` ... once defined, have you looked at that object? In a clear way, it demonstrates my first point, that all elements in a vector are *always* the same class. Do you instead mean `list`?

Answer (score 1):

Problems with that approach:

1. In R, in a vector, all elements must be the same class. If this means that you have a number and a string defined, then they are both strings. See the contents of your `vector` to see this:

   ```r
   vector <- c(10L, 3.8, FALSE, "HELLO")
   vector
   # [1] "10"    "3.8"   "FALSE" "HELLO"
   ```
2. While `function(x = vector)` seems like a good idea to provide a sane default value, this is bad for two reasons:

   1. It relies on the presence of a specific object in the calling environment. While this by itself is not bad, it should be done in a way that either will not fail or fails with *clarity* if the object cannot be found. I've occasionally done something like:

      ```r
      func <- function(x) {
        if (missing(x) && exists("otherobject")) x <- otherobject
        ...
      }
      ```

      One caution from this is `exists("vector")` will always be true because of the function `base::vector` (leading me to the next point), I suggest perhaps you call your object `vec` instead.

      BTW: this really adds very little convenience here, and carries a bit more risk than necessary. I suggest you don't use it, instead requiring the user to provide it in the call.
   2. In its current state, while you have `vector` defined as your vector and it does exist, if you forget to define it in a future R session and then call this function, it will fail with `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`, which is not helpful. Why? Because it finds `base::vector`, and `as.character(base::vector)` cannot work.
3. The use of `is.character(as.character(.))` (and `is.numeric(as.numeric(.))`) is defeating yourself. If something *can* be coerced to `character` (and `numeric`), then it will, and then it will pass the `is.*` test. Period. The only time `is.*(as.*(.))` will not be `TRUE` is when it fails (as in `as.*(base::vector)`. One must do the test without coercing/casting first.
4. Mild note: `for (i in 1:length(x))` makes sense, but if for some reason you pass a vector/list of length `0`, *this will fail*. Why? Intuitively, length 0 suggests that the `for` loop would not iterate, but `1:length(x)` (with an empty vector) reduces to `1:0` which is length 2, so `i` will be `1` and then `0`. It is better to use `for (i in seq_along(x))`, which will do `1:length(x)` when it is not empty, and will do nothing when it is empty.

I'm going to assume that you instead mean to test each element of a `list`, in which different classes can coexist:

```r
data_types <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (is.character(x[[i]])) {
      print('it is a character')
    } else if (is.numeric(x[[i]])) {
      print('it is a number')
    } else {
      print('it is neither a number nor a character')
    }
  }
}
mylist <- list(10L, 3.8, FALSE, "HELLO")
data_types(mylist)
# [1] "it is a number"
# [1] "it is a number"
# [1] "it is neither a number nor a character"
# [1] "it is a character"
```

Or one could just use:

```r
sapply(mylist, typeof)
# [1] "integer"   "double"    "logical"   "character"
```

You can also use `class` instead of `typeof`, but some objects in R have two or more strings there (e.g., `class(Sys.time())`), so it's not always as homogeneous a return value).